# What is the conceptual difference between different types of Taylor series' remainders, namely, Lagrange, integral and cauchy form of the remainder?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Are they different ways of representing the same quantity, i.e., the error in the approximation? Or are they quantitatively different too? If so, why? Why are we not able to reach the same result using any one of these? For example, when dealing with the Taylor series expansion of ln(1+x), Lagrange and cauchy forms lead to different results.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059461/differences-among-cauchy-lagrange-and-schl%C3%B6milch-remainder-in-taylors-formula