# Error approximation for Taylor polynomials

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

Let $p_{n}(x)$ be the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ of the function
$$\boxed{\ f(x)=\log{(1-x)} \quad\text{about   $a=0$.}\ }$$

(a)  How large should $n$ be such that $\vert f(x) - p_{n}(x)\vert\le 10^{-4}$ for $-0.5\le x\le0.5$?

(b) Does this choice of $n$ change if $x$ lies between $[-1, 0.5]$?

---

**Part a)** From repeated differentiation we see that

$$
 \frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}\log(1-x)=(-1)^{2n+1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(1-x)^{n}}$$

and, from

$$
   \vert R_{n}\vert \le \frac{\vert(x-a)\vert^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\max_{a<c<x}   |f^{(n+1)}(c)|,
$$
we obtain
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  &                   &\vert R_{n} \vert                    &\le \frac{\vert{x}\vert^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\max_{0<c<0.5} \left\lvert(-1)^{2n+1}\frac{n!}{(1-c)^{n+1}}\right\rvert \tag{1}\\ 
  &\implies\quad &                                    &\le \frac{\vert{x}^{n+1}\vert}{n+1}\max_{0<c<0.5} \left\lvert\frac{1}{(1-c)^{n+1}}\right\rvert \tag{2}\\  
  &\implies \quad&                                           &\le \frac{\vert{2x}\vert^{n+1}}{n+1}.\tag{3}\\
  &\implies \quad&\vert{R_{n}\vert}                                           &\le \frac{1}{n+1}.\tag{4}\\
\end{alignat*}
Now,
$$
   \frac{1}{n+1}<10^{-4}\implies R_{9999} <10^{-4}.
$$

---

**Part b)** If we're allowed a value of $x=-1$, we may subsitute this in step $(3)$; however, this yields

$$
   \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}<10^{-4}
$$

giving $n=-1$, which doesn't make sense. What am I doing wrong, and can someone help me with part b?

Comment: Step $(3)$ is too late. Try step $(2)$.

Comment: Note that for the series remainder of the power series you get $$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k\right|\le \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty|x|^k=\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1-|x|)},$$ which gives for $|x|\le0.5$ the more manageable inequality $$\frac{2^{-n}}{n+1}<10^{-4}.$$ This is satisfied for $n=10$, much smaller. There may be forms of the Taylor remainder term that are better suited to this task, start with the integral form.

Comment: @metamorphy I think it still gives you the same answer because pluging in $-1$ gives $ \frac{1}{n+1}\max_{0<c<0.5} \left\lvert\frac{1}{(1-c)^{n+1}}\right\rvert$ and picking $c=.5$ which gives the max value gives  $ \frac{1}{n+1} \lvert 2^{n+1}\rvert.$ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @LutzL If I may ask, where does the right side of the inequality come from? (more specifically the series)

Comment: It comes from $\frac1{n+1+k}<\frac1{n+1}$ which gives an upper bound by a geometric series.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307077/115115 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1059461/115115 for a treatment of the Taylor expansion remainder with the Schlömilch remainder term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no indication in the task that a Taylor remainder term has to be used. Thus explore the full Taylor series $$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}k.$$
This power series has radius of convergence equal $1$.

For positive $x$ use the remainder estimate
$$
1>x\ge 0\implies |\ln(1-x)-p_n(x)|\le\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k\le \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1-x)},
$$
For negative $x$, the series is alternating. By the Leibniz test, the remainder of the series is smaller than the next term after the partial sum, thus
$$
-1<x<0\implies |\ln(1-x)-p_n(x)|\le \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1}
$$
To get both error terms below $10^{-4}$ for $|x|\le 0.5$, the first bound is the worse one and gives 
$$
\frac{2^{-n}}{n+1}\le 10^{-4}.
$$
Now remember $2^{10}=1024\sim 10^3$ to find $n=10$ sufficient to satisfy this inequality.

While the second bound guarantees convergence for $x\in[-1,0]$, the remainder in $x=-1$ has size $\frac1{n+1}$ so that much more terms are required.

Comment: You need to restrict $x<1$ for positive $x$ for convergence of the geometric series and whatnot. Also you mean to have $2^{10}>10^3$ I presume.

Comment: I left the bounds from the radius of convergence as implicit, now they are explicit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $-1\notin[0,0.5]$. Instead you should have

$$|R_n(-1)|\le\frac{|-1|^{n+1}}{n+1}\max_{-1\le c\le0}\left|\frac1{(1-c)^{n+1}}\right|$$

from which one can see this reduces down to

$$|R_n(-1)|\le\frac1{n+1}$$

Secondly, for negative values of $x$, it suffices to note that $-\frac1nx^n$ is alternating and decreasing in magnitude, so the magnitude of the first omitted term bounds the error:

$$|R_n(x)|\le\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1}\tag{$\forall x\le0$}$$

Third, for $x\in[0,1)$, a better remainder is given using

$$|R_n(x)|=\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k\right|\le\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1-x)}\tag{$\forall x\in[0,1)$}$$

as pointed out by [LutzL](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353918/error-approximation-for-taylor-polynomials#comment6902913_3353918).

However, for negative $x$, an improved series can be found using log rules. Note that

$$\ln(1-x)=-\ln\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)=-\ln\left(1+\frac x{1-x}\right)$$

and that

$$\left|\ln(1-x)+P_n\left(\frac x{x-1}\right)\right|=\left|R_n\left(\frac x{x-1}\right)\right|\le\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1-x)^{n+2}}\tag{$\forall x\le0$}$$

which converges faster. For example,

$$\left|\ln(2)+P_n\left(\frac12\right)\right|\le\frac1{(n+1)2^{n+2}}$$

which only requires $10$ terms to approximate $\ln(2)$ with a margin of error of $10^{-4}$.