# Convergence of Taylor Series of Function

Tags: calculus

How do we prove that the McLearin series of $\ln(1+x)$ converges to $\ln(1+x)$ for every $x$ in the interval of convergence? Using Taylor's inequality, one can show this in the case $x > -1/2$. But, how do we show this in the case $x$ is between between $-1$ and $-1/2$?

Comment: Integrate the geometric series with remainder.

Comment: Compare the Taylor series to a power series that you know converges.

Comment: You can argue as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307077/taylor-series-for-logarithm-converges-towards-logarithm).

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of the following theorem. If  functions $f_n(x)$ are continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ and the series $$S(x_0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x_0)$$ is convergent for some $a\le x_0\le b,$ while the series $$ T(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(x)$$ is uniformly convergent on $[a,b],$ then the function $S(x)$ is differentiable and $S'(x)=R(x).$

We apply this theorem to $$f_k(x)=
 {(-1)^{k+1}x^k\over k},\quad |x|\le 1-\delta,\qquad x_0=0$$ Hence the function $$S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty   {(-1)^{k+1}x^k\over k},$$ satisfies $S(0)=0$ and
$$S'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}x^{k-1}={1\over 1+x},\quad |x|\le 1-\delta $$ Therefore $S(x)=\ln(1+x)$ for $|x|\le 1-\delta.$ As $\delta>0$ was arbitrary $S(x)=\ln(1+x)$ for $|x|<1.$

The same theorem can be used to prove that if a function $f(x)$is represented by a power series $f(x)=\sum a_nx^n,$ $|x|<1,$ then it is the MacLaurin series of $f.$

**Remark**
No integral calculus is needed, nor  estimates of the remainder in the MacLaurin formula.